# Workflow with Google Colab notebooks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, workflow, airflow, google-colaboratory, gcloud

I've been looking for it, and I didn't find any example. I thought there might be some examples using Airflow, but I didn't find either.

Question is: anyone knows if I can do an automated Workflow with Google Colab notebooks?

Meaning by workflow, for example: running a notebook that loads a .csv (from Google Drive) and then exports another one, after that running another notebook that loads the last export as an input and runs, then running two other ones in parallel... etc.

Any example or comment will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I think this [tutorial](https://medium.com/dair-ai/pytorch-1-2-quickstart-with-google-colab-6690a30c38d) might be useful.